# .NET MVC 3 Validation default ErrorMessageResourceType

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, localization

I want to localize the values of Validation attributes. I have:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ComparePassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization.labels))]
```

The question is, how can I specify a default `ErrorMessageResourceType`? The resources will always be coming from `Localization.labels`, so I don't want to set the `ErrorMessageResourceType` for every validation attribute usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class MyCompareAttribute : CompareAttribute
{
    public MyCompareAttribute(string otherProperty): base(otherProperty)
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization.labels);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[MyCompare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ComparePassword")]
```

Comment: Thanks, are there other options where the default attribute would remain intact? Like wrapping the CompareAttribute or something?

Comment: @jaap, none that I can think of at the moment.